# Disable Scrolling UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, uiwebview

How can I disable scrolling in a `UIWebView`? I also would like to disable the "scrolling bounce".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24):

On iOS 5.x, UIWebView has a backing `scrollView` property:

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

On iOS 4.x and earlier, UIWebView itself inherits from ScrollView:

```
webView.scrollEnabled = NO;
webView.bounces = NO;
```

If you want to check for being on iOS 4 or 5, you can test for UIWebView responding to the scrollView property getter:

```
if ([webView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)]) {
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
} else {
    webView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    webView.bounces = NO;
}
```